# Javascript - Show Hidden div with slide effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I add a slide effect to show my hidden div ?

```js
   function show() {
    var x = document.getElementById("info");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

```html
<a onclick="show()"> Test </a>

<div id="info" style="display:none;">
   <a href="" >1111111111111111111111111111111</a>
</div>
```

Thank you by advance.

Comment: You can use CSS transitions, jQuery animations, or write your own plain vanilla JavaScript code to loop and change the position of the div. However I see no attempt on your part to accomplish this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446658/javascript-add-transition-between-displaynone-and-displayblock

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - add transition between display:none and display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446658/javascript-add-transition-between-displaynone-and-displayblock)

Comment: Post the CSS you have tried

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this with jquery 3.3.1 :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#info").toggle(300);
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="show">SHOW HIDDEN DIV</a>

<div id="info" style="display:none;">I WAS HIDDEN</div>
```